# Constant-sized vector class?

Tags: c++, c++03

Is there a C++ standard type for holding a vector having a constant size? For example, something like a tuple with all element types being the same, so I only have to provide the size as a template argument?

I would like to have the same/similar behavior as when using `std::vector`, but the type should be as compact and efficient as a raw array (so no dynamic allocation, no run-time size information, etc.)

I prefer a **C++03-compatible solution**, so reusing a `std::tuple` isn't what I want.

Does the following class do what I want?

```
template<typename T, int N>
struct vec
{
    T component[N];

    // (+ some logic and accessors like operator[]...)
};

// concrete example:
vec<int,3> myVector;
```

Does it really differ from just saying `T myVector[N]` (concrete example `int myVector[3]`)? Because that's what I am currently doing but I'm experiencing a couple of problems, since raw arrays are "just pointers" (+ size information) and can't be used as return values as well as aren't really passed by value (no deep copy occures).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++11 has `std::array`; which is basically the same as you wrote.

For C++03, use `boost::array` which is basically compatible to `std::array`.

Comment: Thanks, so just replicating this class in my project makes me happy? (Because as stated in the question, I want C++03 compatibility)

Comment: @leemes, There are iterators and everything as well. `boost::array` is basically a C++03 version. It's not a standard class, but it's a precursor to one :)

Comment: @leemes: No reason to replicate it; just pick the Boost one. Since the C++11 one is based on the Boost version, this is future-proof.

Comment: @MSalters - if I remember correctly, the Boost one is based on the C++ TR1 one.

Comment: @PeteBecker: ... which in turn was based on the older Boost one (Boost.array was introduced in v1.17, 2000 whereas TR1 was published in 2005). No surpise, the development of Boost and the standard are intertwined.

Comment: @MSalters - but TR1 was **started** long before 2005.

Comment: So Boost is somewhat like a C++ standard preview :) I added it to the answer.